# mongodb + java + iso date search

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

In my `mongo db` database i have column like this.

```
"created_on" : ISODate("2014-07-02T01:38:48.713Z");
```

In order to to search this column am giving the following query:

```
db.XYZ.find({ "created_on" : ISODate("2014-07-02T01:38:48.713Z")})
```

Now i want to use java for retrieving this data from database:
My query is like:

```
 DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-07-02T01:38:48.713Z" );
 BasicDBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject("created_on", dateTime);
 DBCursor cursor = table.find(query);
```

but am not getting anything query is returning 0 rows??

Any body please help how to set `iso` `date` from java.

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb driver does not work with DateTime currently. You have to use java.util.Date